# Import identical txt files (same file name and same columns) from different subfolders and merging them as one dataframe in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, operating-system, listdir

I am trying to read identical txt files from multiple subfolders (file names and columns are same but content is different) and merge them as a master data frame. Files are located in separate subfolders whose names indicate different periods. The first picture shows the subfolders under Main_Folder:
[image]

And the picture below shows the files that are included under each period subfolder:
[image]

My end goal is to read and merge Cells.txt files from Period_2020 and Period_2021 subfolders by creating a data frame named as "Cells". When appending/merging Cells files, period information should be carried from the subfolders they belonged to and it should be written as a new column on the merged master data frame.
I tried to use listdir(), os.walk with for loops but never got there. I appreciate if someone can bring a for loop solution or share any automated approach.

Comment: What do the contents of the files look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

root_dir = './Main_folder/'

data = {}
for filename in pathlib.Path(root_dir).glob('**/Cells.txt'):
    period = filename.parent.name.split('_')[1]
    data[period] = pd.read_csv(filename)

Cells = pd.concat(data).droplevel(1).rename_axis('Period').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> Cells
  Period  A  B  C
0   2020  1  2  3
1   2021  4  5  6
```

Files:

```
>>> %cat Main_folder/Period_2020/Cells.txt
A,B,C
1,2,3

>>> %cat Main_folder/Period_2021/Cells.txt
A,B,C
4,5,6
```

Comment: This was definetely what I wanted to get. Thanks a lot for the solution!